# Math.random not working

Tags: javascript

I'm not able to generate value to place X in an random location within a box. Any idea what is wrong?

```
   var putAnXBtn = document.getElementById("putAnXButton");
putAnXBtn.onclick = function(){

        var theBox = document.getElementById("putAnX");

        // width and height of the box 
        var width = theBox.clientWidth;
        var height = theBox.clientHeight;


        var yPosition = Math.random()* width; // Not able to generate a value between 0 and the height
        var xPosition = Math.random()* height;  //Not able to generate a value between 0 and the width


      var theXElement = document.getElementById("theX");
        theXElement.innerHTML="X";
        theXElement.style.top = parseInt(yPosition)+'px';
        theXElement.style.left = parseInt(xPosition)+'px';

 }
```

Comment: can you please show your html as well?

Comment: Check `width` and `height` are as you expect

Comment: I'll take a wild guess, `theX` has no position set, so setting a top and left value doesn't move it. Set the position to `relative` for `theX` in CSS, and it will work.

Comment: Either that, or you included that code before the elements in the DOM.

Comment: can you share the HTML?

Comment: Ping, here it is working -> http://jsfiddle.net/sEXgM/1/

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/KuFkN/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use

```
Math.floor(Math.Random() * width)
Math.floor(Math.Random() * height)
```

plus you have your `height` and `width` inverted while generating the random position.

Change this:

```
var yPosition = Math.random() * width;
var xPosition = Math.random() * height;
```

to this:

```
var yPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * height);
var xPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * width);
```

otherwise the X could be created outside of the container boundaries.

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/9t46F/

Comment: Thanks it worked, but I'm not able to see difference when using Math.floor or just Math.random. Fiddle act the same both ways. I'm new here, so what do I know?

Comment: see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) to understand what `Math.floor()` does. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VdZe3/) an example that shows the different results

Comment: Ok I think I understand, but why is Fiddle acting the same on way or the other?

Comment: see my previous comment (second link). the result shown is the same, but the value provided (x and y coordinates) are different..